# My script produces the same output when using $RANDOM

Tags: bash, random

I am trying to print a random `n` letter word, where I input `n` from the command line itself, but for some reason my script is giving me the same answer every time when using the same value for `n`.

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                       
num=$1
egrep "^.{$num}$" /usr/share/dict/words | head -n $RANDOM| tail -n 1
```

I am calling my script like:

```
$ bash var3.sh 5
étude             # always the same output when using 5 

$ bash var3.sh 3
zoo               # always the same output when using 3
```

where `var3.sh` is the name of my script and 5 is the length of the word I want to print randomly.

How do I get it to print a truly random word?

Comment: `$RANDOM` is pretty likely to be greater than the number of *n*-letter words for most values of *n* (95.7% of the time for *n* = 3 for me).

Comment: Are you looking to print a random word completely, even if it isn't a word or print it randomly from the dict?

Comment: If your task is related to security (for example to create a password), you should use a tool made for that task. Otherwise, it is possible to use `shuf` or `sort -R` as suggested in the answers. You can also use `$RANDOM`, but in a more advanced way. All these tools produce results that can be predicted (they are not truly random), but they are fast and good enough for many purposes.

Comment: Maybe they use [this method](https://xkcd.com/221/) (obligatory XKCD reference)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It doesn't. But $RANDOM returns big numbers (between 0 and 32767) which, especially for words of limited lengths, shows the same result, as the `head` portion probably returns all the results of the grep (for 3, there are only 819 matches in my `/usr/share/dict/words`).

Better solution might be to shuffle the results:

`egrep "^.{$num}$" /usr/share/dict/words | sort -R | tail -n 1`

where `-R` means `--random-sort` (a GNU `sort` extension).

Comment: Why `tail`? That made sense in OP's script, but since you're shuffling you could as well use `head`, and then `sort` should be able to detect the broken pipe and not bother shuffling the rest of the lines.

Comment: @PeterTaylor probably a good tip. Using tail is just a habit of mine... In the end, I'd probably prefer even more the `shuf -n1`, which is one pipe less...

Answer (score 19):

A simple method to print an arbitrary *num*-letter word uses `shuf`:

```
egrep "^.{$num}$" /usr/share/dict | shuf -n1
```

The `shuf` command outputs a random permutation of the input, and the `-n1` flag tells it to only output the first item from this result.

Comment: or `grep -Ex ".{$num}"`. Or `awk 'length == n' n="$num"'`.

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, the main issue with your code is that `$RANDOM` more often than not is going to be a value much larger than then number of words of a certain length.

Using `awk` only:

```
$ awk -v len="$num" 'length == len { word[i++]=$0 }
                     END { print word[int(i*rand())] }' /usr/share/dict/words
Bosniac
```

The program reads in all lines from the given file that are of a certain length.  These are stored in the array `words`.

At the end, a random element from this array is selected and printed.